# Automating MIDI to Audio rendering

Tags: midi, sampler, kontakt

I have MIDI files that I need to convert to audio files. I typically do this by creating a track in my DAW, assigning to the track a sampler with the sound I need, dropping the MIDI track in there, and exporting the audio. I'm doing this a lot, it is becoming impractical and I would love to improve this workflow. Does any sampler (Kontakt, UVI...) allow some sort of "offline" rendering (where I would just give it the MIDI as input and get audio as output, according to my samples and settings)? Or is there another method I'm not aware of?

Comment: There are many MIDI -> audio converters, including a lot of online structures, but I don't know of anything that will slipstream to a specific sample set. They tend to be "GM".

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, yes I saw a few of those but indeed I'm looking for something that I can set to my own sounds (with a proper sampler, not soundfonts or the likes...)